# python library to beep motherboard speaker

Tags: python, speaker

I need a python way to beep the system/motherboard speaker independent of the speakers attached to my computer. I don't always have the speakers turned on, so i need to beep the motherboard speaker.

All the libraries i've seen (winsound especially), just play a sound through the speakers attached to my computer. I'd like to beep the system/motherboard speaker.

Is there a way to beep the system speaker? I'm okay with Windows dependent libraries.

Answer (score 2):

just print `'\a'` to stdout

```py
print '\a'   # for python3, print('\a')
```

if you don't want a newline be printed

```py
print '\a\b', # for python3. print('\a\b', end='')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: What's the difference between using your way and the one recommended by aIKid?

Comment: The result is the same. '\a' is '\x07'. But in order to print a '\a' character, you don't have to call `echo` as a subprocess, just print it. `echo` is a simple command for printting. Why not just print it in python code?

Answer (score 0):

Use a call to the command line:

```
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> call(["echo", u'\x07'])
```

As `$ echo ^G` - `^G` is the character for motherboard beep - will produce that sound, to do it with python you only have to execute the comand.